# Cannot assign an inst variable in Switch "--user-data-dir" in Selenium Wedriver Chrome

Tags: ruby, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have the following code and i want to create a user Directory with the name 'mydir' where chrome should output console logs, but wat happens is it creates a directory #{dir} instead. I also tried using CONST Variables still the same result. Can some help me out?

```
require "selenium-webdriver"
class MyClass
dir='mydir'
@driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome, :switches => %w[--ignore-certificate-errors --user-data-dir=#{dir} --enable-logging]
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `%w` literal is similar to using single quotes for Strings. There is no interpolation. As a result, the `--user-data-dir` is exactly what was typed - "#{dir}". To enable interpolation, you need to use a capital W - ie `%W`:

You can see the difference with:

```
dir = 'mydir'

# Without interpolation
p %w[--user-data-dir=#{dir}]
#=> ["--user-data-dir=\#{dir}"]

# With interpolation
p %W[--user-data-dir=#{dir}]
#=> ["--user-data-dir=mydir"]
```

In the end, your script would become:

```
require "selenium-webdriver"
class MyClass
dir='mydir'
@driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome, :switches => %W[--ignore-certificate-errors --user-data-dir=#{dir} --enable-logging]
```